# How to display data from a list on a separate row

Tags: python, django

I am building an inventory system, I have a page where sell history can be viewed by category and it will display all items sold, quantity sold, total quantity in stock, quantity left, sales amount, profit and so on....  Anytime I search by category (e.g stationaries), the display is shown below.

```
Item Name    stock qty    sold qty     total stock   total amount            profit
Books          990        45 75 60     1035 900 990   14567 15666 12666    1777 1555 17777
Sciences       825        45 75 60     1035 900 990    14567 15666 12666    1777 1555 17777
Comics         930        45 75 60     1035 900 990    14567 15666 12666    1777 1555 17777
```

But I actually want is:

```
Item Name    stock qty    sold qty     total stock   total amount            profit
Books          990        45            1035          14567                  1777 
Sciences       825        75            1035          15666                  1555 
Comics         930        60            990           12666                  17777
```

The Item names and stock qty are been called from the database and appended to a list. for the quantity of item sold, i called every instance of such item from the database and calcuate their total and then append to a list. So I want to dispaly them for their respective item, same goes for amount and profir. All I just want is how to manipulate the template so as to display it appropriately.  My view code is given below:

```
def search_category (request):
    collate=[]
    gains=[]
    amount=[]
    name=[]
    store=[]
    qty=[]
    if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
        q = request.GET.get('q','')
        items = Item.objects.filter(category__name__exact=q)
        for item in items:
            collate.append(item.subcategory.subcategoryname)
            qty.append(int(item.quantity))
        len_collate=len(collate)
        count=0
        #for pick in collate:
        keep1=[]
        amt_save=[]
        gain_save=[]
        t=[]
        all_amt_save=[]
        #sum=0
        #t_amount=0
        #t_gain=0
        while count < len_collate:
            soldqty=[]

            #histories = RecordSales.objects.filter(ItemName__subcategoryname__exact=pick)#here

            histories = RecordSales.objects.filter(ItemName__subcategoryname__exact=collate[count])
            lenght=len(histories)
            for history in histories:


                soldqty.append(history.quantity)

                #keep1=[] #array to store sum
                len_qty=len(soldqty)
                #count=0
                #while count < lenght:
                sum=0
                sums=[]
                t_stock=[]
                #for num in soldqty:
                count_qty=0
                #for num in soldqty:
                while count_qty < len_qty:
                    sum=sum + soldqty[count_qty]
                    #t_stock=qty[count_qty] + sum
                    count_qty=count_qty + 1
                amount.append(history.total)
                t_amount=0

                amt_count=0
                while amt_count < len(amount):
                    t_amount=t_amount + amount[amt_count]
                    amt_count=amt_count + 1
                gains.append(history.profit)
                t_gain=0
                gain_count=0
                while gain_count < len(gains):
                    t_gain=t_gain + gains[gain_count]
                    gain_count=gain_count + 1
                name.append(history.ItemName)



            #keep1.append(sum)
            len_keep1=len(keep1)
            amt_save.append(t_amount)
            gain_save.append(t_gain)
            count=count + 1
            keep1.append(sum)
            all_amt_count=0
            all_amt_total=0
            while all_amt_count < len(amt_save):
                all_amt_total= all_amt_total + amt_save[all_amt_count]

                #all_amt_save.append(all_amt_total)
                all_amt_count=all_amt_count + 1
            all_g_count=0
            all_g_total=0
            while all_g_count < len(gain_save):
                all_g_total=all_g_total + gain_save[all_g_count]
                all_g_count=all_g_count + 1
            t_count=0
            while t_count < len(keep1):
                t_stock=keep1[t_count] + qty[t_count]

                t_count=t_count + 1
            store.append(t_stock)
            total_amount=0
            keep_total=[]
            for total in amount:
                total_amount=total_amount + total
                keep_total.append(total_amount)
                    #total_amount=0


        return render_to_response('sell_category.html',
        {'items':items,'query': q,'keep1':keep1,'name':name,'items':items,
        'keep_total':keep_total,'t':store,'amt_save':amt_save,'gain_save':gain_save,'all_amt':all_amt_total,'t_gain':all_g_total,'len':len_keep1,

        })
    else:
        return render_to_response('sell_category.html', {'error': True})
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you're appending everything to a list then you can use `zip()` and some string formatting to get the desired result:

```
items=['Books','Sciences','Comics']
stock_qua=[990,825,930]
sold_qua=[45,75,60]
total_sto=[1035,1035,990]
total_amt=[14576,15666,12666]
profit=[1777,1555,1777]

print "{0:12s}{1:12s}{2:12s}{3:15s}{4:15s}{5:12s}".format("Item Name", "stock qty","sold qty","total stock","total amount","profit")

for item,stock,sold,tot_st,amt,pro in zip(items,stock_qua,sold_qua,total_sto,total_amt,profit):
    print "{0:12s}{1:^10d}{2:^10d}{3:^15d}{4:^15d}{5:^12d}".format(item,stock,sold,tot_st,amt,pro)
```

**output:**

```
Item Name   stock qty   sold qty    total stock    total amount   profit      
Books          990        45         1035           14576         1777    
Sciences       825        75         1035           15666         1555    
Comics         930        60          990           12666         1777
```